# Streaming using the vlcControl shows bad quality

Tags: c#, vlc, rtsp, libvlc

I have installed Vlc.DotNet.Forms where I have put the vlcControl1 to the Form.

I am streaming using the below code. But the quality of the stream is quite bad.
It is blurry and fuzzy. When I look in Chrome it looks very good.

I wonder if there is any kind of quality setting for the vlcControl1 that one can do to
improve the quality?

```js
            vlcControl1.SetMedia(new Uri("rtsp://192.168.1.4:554/11"), null);
            vlcControl1.Play();
```

Comment: `I am not streaming using the below code.`  Did you mean that you *are* streaming with that code?  If not, how is that code relevant?

Comment: I am sorry I ofcourse mean `I am now streaming using the below code`. That was my mistake. So back to my question again then. :)

Comment: How does it look in the VLC app?